# Google Drive для хранения данных

Tags: java, android, база-данных, хранение-данных

Приложение для `Android`. Нужно запрашивать и сохранять данные (переменные) вне смартфона, чтобы при обновлении приложения данные не терялись. Можно ли использовать для этого `Google Drive`? Или что иное?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте базу данных. А при обновлении настройте миграцию

Comment: mysql или какую?

Comment: SQLite, но проще используйте библиотеку ORM'ку какую-нибудь, например Room, GreenDao и т.д. Загуглите, примеров очень много в интернете